# Making mobile nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was creating a responsive website so I decided to create the tablet and mobile version and wanted to be as usual many developers do when creating a small device nav bar(burger bar). So I can add class to html file using javascript but after that there is a problem that i'm stock an hour. Thanks
here you can see the code:

[codepen](https://codepen.io/amini-py/pen/MWJQJVv)

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", show);
function show() {
    let list = document.querySelector("ul");
    if (list.className != "hidden") {
        list.className = "bar";
    } else if (list.className == "hidden") {
        list.className -= "bar";
        list.className = "hidden";
    }
}
```

```css
header button {
    float: right;
    margin: 25px 25px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

header button .fa-bars {
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: white;
}

header img {
    padding: 25px 75px;
}

header nav {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 75px;
}

.bar li {
    padding: 30px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px #cecece solid;
    width: 85%;
}

.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/logo-black.png" alt="NewsBit" /></a>
    <button type="button">hello</button>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">GUIDS & ANALYTICS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">EXPLAINED</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ICON CALENDAR</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Your relevant, "*[mcve]*" code should be in your question not in an external resource. An external demo is useful, and perhaps even a bonus, but it doesn't replace the need to have your code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS**

- In mobile, `ul` should be hidden by default and when you click you need to `show`.
- In large device, `button` should not be there.

**JS**
There is a `out-of-box` method `toggle` on `classList` to toggle the class. No need to check conditionally.

Hope it helps ☺☺

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", show);

function show() {
  let list = document.querySelector("ul");
  list.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
header button {
  float: right;
  margin: 25px 25px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header button .fa-bars {
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: white;
}

header img {
  padding: 25px 75px;
}

header nav {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 75px;
}

.bar li {
  padding: 30px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px #cecece solid;
  width: 85%;
}

ul {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  ul {
    display: block;
  }
  button {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/logo-black.png" alt="NewsBit" /></a>
  <button type="button">
            show/hide
        </button>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">GUIDS & ANALYTICS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">EXPLAINED</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ICON CALENDAR</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```